# SpyOn a modal whether a click event has been called in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How do you `spyon` the click event when it is programmatically triggered in a function?

HTML

```
<button
  type="button"
  id="foo"
  hidden
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#foo-modal"
  (click)="onOpenModal('foo')"
></button>
```

Function

```
onOpenModal(source: any) {
    const modal = document.getElementById(source);

    if (modal) {
      modal.click();
    }
}
```

I tried something like the below test

```
it('should open foo modal', () => {
  const modal = document.getElementById('foo') as HTMLElement;
  spyOn(modal, 'click');

  component.onOpenModal('foo-modal');
  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#foo')).nativeElement.click();

  expect(modal.click]).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

it does work, however; I do not think it is the right way to do the test as removing the `modal.click()` still makes the test succeed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. It is hard to tell from the context of code fragments.  What is the HTML? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @E.Maggini I've updated it

Comment: Your element is hidden by default so I would not expect this to work.